# Guidance on how to implement certain problems in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, filter

For the class `NumberSet`, I have to define the `[]` method so that it takes one argument, which it uses as a filter to select members of the set and returns a new set containing those elements.

For example, I have

```
Filter.new { |number| number.even? }
```

and

```
SignFilter.new(:non_negative)
```

which are classes that I must construct.

I also have to define the `&` and `|` operators so that they work with the filters. Something along the lines of

```
numbers[SignFilter.new(:non_negative) & Filter.new { |number| number.even? }]
```

The class so far is:

```
class NumberSet
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @arr=[]
  end
  def each (&block)
    @arr.each do |member|
      block.call (member)
    end
  end
  def << number
    @arr<<number unless  @arr.include?(number)
  end
end
```

For `Filter` I think something like works:

```
class Filter
  def initialize
    yield
  end
end
```

My biggest problem is the `[]`, `$`and `|` parts, which I have no idea how to do.

---

What I want to accomplish is :

---

```
numbers = NumberSet.new
  [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |number|
  numbers << number
end
numbers[SignFilter.new(:non_negative) & Filter.new { |number| number.even?}].to_a
#=>[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: It helps us help you if you take the time to format your question so it is more readable. Please use correct grammar and punctuation.

Comment: @theTinMan Ok I will see to it.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you show with an example--including your expected output--what you want to accomplish?  Please do so by editing, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it.

**Code**

*SignFilter class*

```
class SignFilter
  def initialize(sign)
    @sign = sign
  end
  def filter
    case @sign
    when :negative
      -> i { i < 0 }
    when :positive
      -> i { i > 0 }
    when :non_negative
      -> i { i >= 0 }
    when :non_positive
      -> i { i <= 0 }
    when :zero
      -> i { i.zero? }
    end
  end
end
```

*Filter class*

```
class Filter
  attr_reader :filter
  def initialize &filter
    @filter = filter
  end
end
```

*NumberSet class*

```
class NumberSet
  def initialize arr
    @arr = arr
  end
  def process(op, sf, f)
    sign_filter = sf.filter
    filter = f.filter 
    @arr.send(op).each { |e| sign_filter.call(e) }
        .send(op).each { |e| filter.call(e) } 
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
sf = SignFilter.new :negative
f = Filter.new { |number| number.even? }
ns = NumberSet.new [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ns.process(:reject, sf, f)
  #=> [1, 3, 5]

sf = SignFilter.new :non_negative
f = Filter.new { |number| number % 3 == 0 }
ns = NumberSet.new [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ns.process(:select, sf, f)
  #=> [0, 3, 6]
```

**Explanation**

Blocks are not objects, so you can't pass them around. They can be converted to procs, however, which are objects (instances of the class [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Proc.html)), and therefore can be passed. You will need to understand procs (and lambdas, which are a type of proc). [Here](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) is a good explanation. (Aside: one thing that's a little confusing about procs is the multitude of ways they can be invoked. For example, if `p -> i { 3*i }`, `p.call(2)`, `p.yield(2)`, `p[2]` and `p.(2)` all return the value `6`.)

Here is what is happening:

- An instance `sf` of the `SignFilter` class is created by passing the symbol denoting the signs of the elements of the array that are to be selected or rejected (`:negative`, `:non_negative` and so on). The symbol is saved in an instance variable `@sign`.
- The `SignFilter` class has a method `filter` which returns a `lambda` based on the value of `@sign`.
- An instance of the `Filter` class is created by passing a block which is received as a `proc` and saved into the instance variable `@filter`, which has a read accessor.
- An instance of the `NumberSet` class is created by passing the array, which is saved into the instance variable `@arr`.
- `NumberSet#process` is passed three arguments: the Enumerable method `:reject` or `:select` (saved into `op`), the `SignFilter` instance (`sf`) and the `Filter` instance (`f`).
- Within `NumberSet#process`, `@arr` is sent `op`, which creates an enumerator (`arr.reject` or `arr.select)`.
- The `SignFilter` lambda is called on each element of the enumerator. An array comprised of a subcollection of `@arr` is returned.
- The returned array is sent `op`, creating another `reject` or `select` enumerator.
- The `Filter` proc is called on the each element of the new enumerator, causing the desired array to be returned.

Considering that both `reject` and `select` are not necessary (either would do), it would have been simpler to just replace `.send(op)` in `NumberSet#process` with, say, `reject`, but I chose to do it this way just to illustrate the generalization.

Notice that it would be easy to generalize `NumberSet#process` to `process(sf,f,o)`, where, as now, `sf` and `f` provide filters and `o` would be an instance of an `Operation` class that specifies a proc to send to the filtered subcollection of `@arr` to invoke an Enumerable method with a block (`map`, `group_by` and so on).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I did the SignFilter and another filter and they bout work well. But the problem is `Filter`, because my program will be automatically tested and graded and for it to work `numbers[Filter.new{|number|number.even?}]` must be a valid expression, but because `Filter.new{|number|number.even?}` is basically an anonymous object, I don't know how to call it on the objects of type `NumberSet`?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, after reading how to pass blocks to methods. Now I have to only do the `&` and `|`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a homework question, I'm not going to give you the full implementation, but I'll see you on your way. The big thing you need to realize here is that methods such as `[]` and `|` can be defined as normal methods in Ruby. In Ruby, you simply send messages (such as `[]`) to a "receiver". How you handle those methods are defined via `def` instructions on your class definition. So, for example:

```
 class Filter
   def |(other_filter)
     # Do some work to build a new filter which is a union of this filter and other_filter
   end
 end

 class SignFilter < Filter
    # SignFilter inherits the & method from Filter, and you can then go on to implement SignFilter-specific functionality
    # ...
 end

 class NumberSet
   def [](filter)
     # Given a filter, apply each of the numbers of this NumberSet to the filter, and return those which pass the filter
   end
 end
```

To invoke those methods, would do something like:

```
 filter = Filter.new {|num| num.even? }
 sign_filter = SignFilter.new(:non_negative)
 union_filter = filter | sign_filter
```

This third line is equivalent to calling:

```
 union_filter = filter.|(sign_filter)
```

or:

```
 union_filter = filter.send("|", sign_filter)
```

In all three cases, the "|" message is sent to the the `filter` instance, with `sign_filter` as an additional argument. You could also do something like:

```
 numset = NumberSet.new(1,2,3,4,5)
 filtered_numbers = numset[union_filter]
```

This second line is equivalent to:

```
 numset.[](union_filter)
 # or
 numset.send("[]", union_filter)
```

The original syntax is just syntactic sugar for those method calls - it's just there because it makes Ruby code look nicer, and helps the programmer mentally map it to common conventions for those kinds of operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few questions. How exactly do I call a `filter` if I want `numbers[Filter.new {|number|number.even?}]`, because here `def [] (filter)
  @arr.select{|number| filter(number)}
 end`, filter is an undefined method

Comment: filter there is a Filter object, not a method; you would need to call some method on the `filter` object.

Comment: Also how do I apply the SignFilter.new(:non_negative) when declaring it , if it doesn't take any arguments. And finally how in the name of god, do I make the `&` and `|` methods so they work.

Comment: Sorry for annoying you, but some clearence is of great help to me.

Comment: SignFilter.new returns a SignFilter instance. You should have some method on that object that you can pass a number or set of numbers to and retrieve a meaningful result from. For the & and | methods, you basically want a Filter which returns either the insection (&) or union (|) of the results of multiple filters.